# Programmatically Set Constraint Height/Width Percent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to set the height and width percent of a Constraint Layout programmatically, however the layout is not resizing.
The code I have so far is

```
val set = ConstraintSet()

set.constrainPercentHeight(R.id.topView, 0.7F)
set.constrainPercentWidth(R.id.topView, 0.3F)

set.applyTo(topConstraintLayout)
```

The xml of my layout is

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/topView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".35"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".30">
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Try to `set.clone(topConstraintLayout)` before setting the percentage.. Also you might need to `topConstraintLayout.requestLayout()` at the end

Comment: Layout arguments are consumed by views parent - it will not cause `ConstraintLayout` to resize itself. They will be handled by parent of `topView` but only if it is a `ConstraintLayout` as well.